# asp.net webform : RegisterClientScriptBlock not working with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms, webforms

i have a problem with RegisterClientScriptBlock method in asp.net.

I use this code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "closeFilt", ";$(function(){$('#filters-container').slideUp(); });", true);
```

but nothing happen and in console i see `jQuery is not defined`.

It render the script block before the footer and of course it doesn't work...

there is any way to make it work??

I found a workaroud

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "closeFilt", "var closeFilt = setInterval(function(){$('#filters-container').slideUp(); clearInterval(closeFilt)},300);", true);
```

it works but its ugly and i'm looking for a better solution... any advice?

Comment: You have an extra semicolon at the start of the first version. Is that affecting it? They're both written a little differently. Remove `;$` from the first one? (Or just the `;`?)

Comment: @wazz the semicolon has no effects and the $ is mandatory for the function... my problem is that it render the script before the initialization of jquery

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find it useful.

This is the way I command to call the RegisterStartupScript function.

First, I use an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void RunScript(this Page _page, String _script)
    {
        String function = @"<script type='text/javascript'> $(function () { " + _script + " }); </script>";
        _page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(_page.GetType(), Key.GetNewKey(), function, false);
    }
}

public static class Key
{
    public static String GetNewKey()
    {
        String _string_key = String.Empty;
        Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        foreach (char _char in Convert.ToBase64String(_guid.ToByteArray()))
        {
            _string_key += char.IsLetterOrDigit(_char) ? _char.ToString() : string.Empty;
        }
        return _string_key;
    }
}
```

Then, this is how I call the function:

```
this.RunScript("alert('Hello world')");
```

any questions let me know.

Comment: The main difference is that the RegisterStartupScript method places the JavaScript at the bottom of the ASP.NET page right before the closing </form> element. The RegisterClientScriptBlock method places the JavaScript directly after the opening <form> element in the page.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667538/The-Difference-Between-Page-ClientScript-RegisterS

Comment: this is a good method, but it still not working, the problem is the it render the script before the initialization of jquery and return `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: well, I use a bundle to load all of my scripts and css dependencies, what do you use or how do you load your dependencies?

Comment: I Just add a script tag in the footer

Comment: try adding the script in the header, then use my code example and let me know if workit

Comment: I use jquery from cdn... Putting inside header wont make everything slower?

Comment: It depends on the connectivity that the client has with the cnd service, I prefer to use it local, but if you use it for cnd I think it does not matter if it is at the end or the beginning, the load is the same.